# Shortest unique substrings of a vector

Tags: r, string, substring

Say I have a character vector of some length,

```
vec <- c("man lives to work", "man works to live")
```

*Starting from the beginning*, I'd now like to find the **shortest unique substrings** (of complete words) in this vector.
In other words, I'm not looking for the shortest substring overall, but I'd like *crop* the string after the word where it becomes unique, in this case after `work` and `lives`, respectively.

So the result should be, in this case:

```
[1] "man lives" "man works"
```

The strings should be cropped *after* `lives`/`works` because that's the earliest point at which they become unique (in this context).
Including `to` would be redundant, because they are already unique.
Including only `man` would not be enough, because `c("man", "man")` is not unique.

(I want to use this to automatically generate valid R names, and `base::make.names()` will do the rest).

How do I do this?

I figured, there *has* to be a package out there which already does this, but couldn't find it.

Comment: Could you please clarify again what you mean by shortest unique substring. In your case, e.g., the string "to" or "to work" would be shorter than "man lives" in terms of the number of characters. Therefore, it is not quite clear what you want.

Comment: yes, thank you @ManuelBickel. I've edited the question to make it clearer.
I'm looking for the shortest "cropped-off" substring, starting from the beginning of the string.
Is that clearer?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. However, it is still not perfectly clear were you want to cut off. You mention something about "complete words". "to" is also a complete word. I guess you want to stop as soon as specific stopwords like "to", "and", etc. occur. Or do you simply want to cut off after the second term is completed? Imagine phrases like "the right to vote" or only "right to vote". What would be the desired output here. Sorry for being so picky, but these choices can make an important difference.

Comment: understood @ManuelBickel.
I have no particular stopwords in mind.
I want to stop *after* `lives`/ `words`, because *including* these words, the two strings become unique. Will update question.

Comment: updated question yet again to explain cutoff @ManuelBickel.

Comment: for `c("the right to vote", "right to vote")`, the desired output would indeed be `c("the", "right")` – though I can see how that's quite crude.

If there are other, established/better ways of abbreviating (potentially long) strings in a human-readable way, that'd be great too, but out of scope here, I guess.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, now I get it - hopefully :-). I think I can provide you with a solution next week in case nobody else proposes one until then.

Comment: Do you always compare *two* strings or can there be any number of strings and you need the shortest substring that makes all of them unique?

Comment: there can be any number of strings @docendodiscimus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a general strategy I would a) check to see if the first word is unique,
b) if not, check if the first two words are unique,
c) continue until unique solutions have been found for each string.

You could implement this usit a `while` loop, or using recursion. Here is an example of the later (UPDATED to preserve order):

```
library(stringi) ## makes string processing easier

vec <- c("man lives to work", "man works to live")

(word.mat <- stri_split_boundaries(vec,
                                   type = "word",
                                   skip_word_none = TRUE,
                                   simplify = TRUE))
##      [,1]  [,2]    [,3] [,4]  
## [1,] "man" "lives" "to" "work"
## [2,] "man" "works" "to" "live"

## function to extract unique words
unique_words <- function(x, # matrix of words
                         n = nrow(x), # number of original strings
                         nc=1 # number of columns (words) to use
                         ) {
    ## join the first nc words
    s <- stri_trim(apply(x[, 1:nc, drop = FALSE], 1, stri_join, collapse = " "))
    ## find non-duplicated word combinations, and store in column 1
    nodups <- !s %in% s[stri_duplicated(s)]
    x[nodups, 1] <- s[nodups]
    ## remove extra words from the matrix
    x[nodups, -1] <- ""
    ## if some strings are not unique, do it again, increasing nc by one
    if(any(x[, 2] != "")) {
        x <- unique_words(x = x, n = n, nc = nc + 1)
    ## otherwise, grab the unique sub-phrases from column 1    
    } else {
        x <- x[, 1]
    }
    ## return the result
    x
}    
## test it out
unique_words(word.mat)
## [1] "man lives" "man works"

## test it out with a more complicated example:
vec <- c("foo", "man lives to eat", "man eats to live",
         "woman lives to work", "woman works to live",
         "we like apples", "we like peaches",
         "they like plums", "they love peas", "bar")
unique_words(stri_split_boundaries(vec,
                                   type = "word",
                                   skip_word_none = TRUE,
                                   simplify = TRUE))
## [1] "foo"             "man lives"       "man eats"        "woman lives"    
## [5] "woman works"     "we like apples"  "we like peaches" "they like"      
## [9] "they love"       "bar"
```

Comment: +1 for elegant solution with recursive use of function (and using the faster stringi package instead of stringr)

Comment: unfortunately, on further inspection, this code screws up the order in some instances. E.g. `vec <- c("man lives to eat", "foo", "man eats to live")` yields `#"foo"       "man lives" "man eats" `.

Comment: Thanks @maxheld I updated the example so that it preserves the order.

Answer (score 1):

```
df %>%  unnest_tokens(word ,words) %>%
  mutate(bigram = substr(word,1,2), 
         trigram = ifelse (nchar(word) >= 3,substr(word,1,3),NA) ,
         four_gram  = ifelse (nchar(word) >= 4, substr(word,1,4), NA), 
         five_gram  = ifelse (nchar(word) >= 5, substr(word,1,5), NA)) %>%
  group_by(bigram) %>%
  mutate(count_bigram = n()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  group_by(trigram) %>%
  mutate(count_trigram = n()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  group_by(four_gram) %>%
  mutate(count_four_gram = n()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  group_by(five_gram) %>%
  mutate(count_five_gram = n()) %>%
  ungroup()   %>% 
  summarise_each(funs(((function(x) {sum(x == 1)})(.))), 
                 count_bigram, count_trigram, 
                 count_four_gram, count_five_gram)



# # A tibble: 1 × 4
#    count_bigram count_trigram count_four_gram count_five_gram
#          <int>         <int>           <int>           <int>
#1            0             0               0               2
```

Comment: thanks @Mouad_S, but this just gives the frequencies and lengths of words, correct?
Maybe my question was poorly formulated, but this was not what I was looking for.

Comment: I edited the code, basically you iterate over the numbers 2,3,4,5...etc, it depends on your data, in this case the string that is sought is of length 5